# Navegar dentro de ViewPager utilizando botones

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un viewPager que me muestra 3 Fragments, pero deseo saber como poner botones dentro de cada una de estas que me permita moverme de uno a otro, es algo similar a lo que ocurre con el TabLayout, pero acá usaria botones!

Answer (score 0):

Es simple lo que debes hacer, si tus botones estan dentro de los fragments debes cominarte con la activity que maneja el viewpager, yo para estos casos uso observables.
En esta [pagina](https://jonathanmelgoza.com/blog/observadores-en-java/) parece facil la explicacion, si no lo entendes, avisame que con gusto te ayudo.

Una vez implementados los observables unicamente te queda implementar la funcion del onUpdate(), te recomiendo pasar en cada notifyObservers() una string constante para que en un switch case diferenciar las opciones.

Entonces

```
public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
switch(){
case "BOTON_1":
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    break;
case "BOTON_2":
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    break;
case "BOTON_3":
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    break;
}
}
```

Con esto si creaste bien el adapter del viewPager, guardaste la variable como atributo, deberia estar :D

EDIT:
Podes hacerlo de una forma un poco mas fea, pero util y rapida
Guarda tu viewPager como atributo PUBLICO y ESTATICO en tu main.

```
public static viewPager mViewPager
```

desde tus fragments en los onClick() de los botones realizas lo siguiente

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(NUMERO_FRAGMENT);
```

Esto del setCurrentItem te funcionaria si tenes bien el adapter, tu viewPager si deslizas para los costados funciona?

Comment: Que es lo que no has podido entender de la respuesta?

Comment: deberias crear los botones, asignarles el onClickListener y luego intervenir en el main activity con los observables

Comment: Amigo, tengo 3 fragment mostrandolos en un viewPager, tengo botones dentro de estos con los que pasare al siguiente fragment o regresare, los botones estan dentro de cada fragment y desde el Main no logro que exista el evento onClick, yo se como lograr el onClick desde mis Fragment pero no se como acceder al viewPager que esta creado en el Main...

Comment: revisaste el link de los observables? son una especie de eventos que vos disparas y que las clases que estan suscriptos a el reaccionan, de todas formas tenes una forma mas fea de hacer las cosas pero te va a funcionar con pocos pasos

Comment: Amigo te explico, yo quiero hacer lo mismo que tiene instagram en su Home, tiene una vista principal y si deslizas hacia la izquierda sale una nueva vista y si presionas el boton volves a la principal y lo mismo pasa con la siguiente vista.

Comment: Intente con el GestureDetector pero solo logro sacar una vista nueva del lado izquierdo y no se como hacerle para poder sacar una vista nueva del lado derecho, asi que se me ocurrio utilizar fragments y mostrarlos en un viewPager, pero ahora quiero agregar esos botones con los que puedo llamar un fragment dentro de este y luego tener un boton allla para poder regresar a la vista principal,  amigo sabes como puedo hacer esto???   es que no logro acceder a este viewPager desde los fragments para asi poder implementar lo que deseo... ayudame por favor!!!

Comment: Leiste el EDIT que añadi?, Entiendo lo que queres hacer, no esta mal,pero no se si estas usando mal los componentes, el viewpager sirve para que al deslizar el dedo de los costados puedas cambiar entre los fragments asociados al view pager, subi tu adapter de viewPager si no no te voy a poder seguir ayudando